# Where does Googlebot crawl from?

Tags: googlebot, gis

I have been looking high and low for the locations from which Googlebot and its brothers and sisters crawl from other than "CA" and am having no luck finding locations specific to crawling. I have found a map of data canters from 2008 (http://bit.ly/mONhf9), I have found Googles own self professed brilliance in their data centers, complete with lovely photos (http://www.google.com/about/datacenters/).

I do know from experience, at least 3 years ago, that the ole' bot would also come from VA... but past that... Nothing.

Can anyone help with this riddle? I'm gathering Google doesnt want ME to know.

Answer (score 5):

Your mileage will vary, but in the case of the most popular website I have access to, the crawls emanate from:

- Illinois (46.35%)
- Arizona (15.68%)
- Wisconsin (14.95%)
- Virginia (11.85%)
- California (11.17%)

The web servers that have been subject to these crawls are located on Amazon, in Virginia.

Here it is on a map: http://www.chrisbrunner.com/2014/04/01/where-does-googlebot-crawl-from/
(I couldn't post it directly, due to this being my first post.)

Again, others will have different experiences, but this is what we observed over the course of March 2014.

Comment: I'm using the MaxMind GeoIP Free database, which is good but can't always resolve the location of Googlebot, from its IP address. PageSpeed Insights registering a response time of 600 milliseconds from my server, a fast SSD-backed machine on a fast network near an internet backbone in London (my server responds much quicker to me). Based on latency, Pagespeed Insights googlebot visits may be based in the USA. If so, does this mean that non-geographically targeted sites should be hosted in the USA to rank well? Then how is this fair to internet users or hosting companies outside the USA?

Comment: @MatthewSlyman I'm with you and have a similar problem. We want to run geo-load balancing which means US traffic hits a US server and UK traffic hits a UK server. By it's nature it means all our US pages will be cached and quick in the US and UK pages cached and quick in the UK *but not vice versa*. Googlebot will index UK pages on the US server due to its geoip which will be slow because they aren't cached. We're concerned Google will rank those pages as slow which is wrong. How to get around this is a challenge!

Answer (score 1):

I've collected information about that topic and I've concluded that GoogleBot crawls from 6 different locations. I haven't been able to precisely put them on the map but seems that 4 of them are in different parts of the States and one of them in Europe.

You have all the details in this post: http://blog.domenech.org/2013/09/where-is-googlebot-crawler-located.html